# Get selected value from HTML - <select>--</select> box

Tags: java, html, servlets, select, null

I am dealing with a web application. I have a HTML - **select** box with 50k string values. From these 50k values user will select one and I want to use that selected value in a SQL where clause for further retrieval. But right now with existing code I am getting null. Code looks like -

```
out.println("<form action=sampleServlet method=POST>");
        out.println("<select name=\"data\">");
        for(int i=0;i<nw.collectdata.length;i++)
        {
            out.println("<option value='"+nw.collectdata[i]+"'>"+nw.collectdata[i]+"</option>");
        }
        out.println("</select>");
        out.println("<button type='submit'>Submit</button>");
        out.println("</form>");
        elements = request.getParameter("data");
        out.println(elements);
```

**elements** is returning null and not selected value.

Comment: Where is the `request` coming from?

Comment: What is this?  Is this servlet code?  onGet maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Is following condition meets on your code:

- `request` is the object of `HttpServletRequest`
- This code is inside method like `doGet` and `doPost`
- Did you click the `submit` button ?

If not please try to meet above condition. I hope this will work.

**Updated:**

I think  here is mistake on your code:
please use and see my following code which was tested on my local pc.

```
out.println("<form action=\"sampleServlet\" method=\"POST\">");
```

instead of

```
out.println("<form action=sampleServlet method=POST>");
```

**servlet code: Test.java**

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        String[] collectdata = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String elements = request.getParameter("data");
        out.println("<form action=\"Test\" method=\"POST\">");
        out.println("<select name=\"data\">");
        for (int i = 0; i < collectdata.length; i++) {
            out.println("<option value='" + collectdata[i] + "'>" + collectdata[i] + "</option>");
        }
        out.println("</select>");
        out.println("<button type='submit'>Submit</button>");
        out.println("</form>");
        elements = request.getParameter("data");
        out.println(elements);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Following is my output:**

[image: pandey]

Now, I am sure and confirm that your list `nw.collectdata` is empty. So You are getting null value. Because if you set only  `String[] collectdata = {};`  instead of `String[] collectdata = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};` on this (MyCode) code you will get null. So my advice to you  is, please get values on list: `nw.collectdata`. And you can also test yourself to my code.

Comment: 1) request is the object of HttpServletRequest                                  2) it is inside servide(){}. but will it make difference?                3) I am clicking submit button.

Comment: It may not be different but something is mistake on your code please see my edited.

Comment: I tested making simple application on my PC and it is working to me. But I do not know why not working to you. See I will post my sample source code.

Comment: For me option values are coming from some other java class and I am setting those values in for loop. Please have a look at this once. I think this is the difference:                                  **for(int i=0;i<nw.collectdata.length;i++)
{
out.println("<option value='"+nw.collectdata[i]+"'>"+nw.collectdata[i]+"</option>");
}**

Comment: Is all value are displaying on your `select list` ?

Comment: Yes.. Values are coming in list but once I select it is showing null. Difference in our code is there only in setting option tag values.

Comment: Actually, if values are displaying then it should not be null. If you follow above steps.

Comment: Ok.. It is showing null itself. But anyways Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry.. its a typo. it is `collectdata.length()`

Comment: I added `String[] collectdata = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};` value and tested myself. It is working to me. See my code...

Comment: Chances that `nw.collectdata` is empty are less because I am getting correct values in the select list for which source is `nw.collectdata`. Even I checked JSP code by **view source** from browser it is giving correct values for `nw.collectdata`

Comment: Just want to ask that can't I do it without `<form>` and a `<button>`? that displaying selected value on same page, just opposite to select list. Even that is showing **`null`**

Answer (score 0):

you should print something like this:

```
<form action="sampleServlet" method="POST">
```

and for printing `"` inside of `"..."` (doable quotation) you need to use `\`.
so you must edit code:

```
out.println("<form action=\"sampleServlet\" method=\"POST\">");
```

**Note:** or you can use `'`!